# HTTP get MultiValueMap response using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, multipartform-data

I need to do RestTemplate request to get response from this method:

```
@GetMapping(value = DEVICE_ID_PATH, produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> getDeviceSummary(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {

        log.debug("REST request to get summary for complex with id = {}", id);

        DeviceSummaryResponse response =
            deviceSummaryMapper.toResponse(mobileComplexService.getSummary(id));

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> deviceSummary = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

        deviceSummary.add("route", new HttpEntity<>(response.getRoute(), getStreamHeader()));
        deviceSummary.add("config", new HttpEntity<>(response.getConfig(), getJsonHeader()));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(deviceSummary, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I try create this Rest query:

```
public MobileComplexSummaryDto getSummary(String deviceIp, Integer apiServerPort) throws DeviceSummaryObtainingException {
        log.debug("Requesting mobile complex device summary for ip = {}...", deviceIp);

        ResponseEntity<DeviceSummaryResponse> response;

        try {
            response = restTemplate.exchange(
                String.format(URL_TEMPLATE, deviceIp, apiServerPort, coreComplexApiAware.deviceSummaryEndpoint()),
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new HttpEntity<>(Map.of(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)),
                DeviceSummaryResponse.class
            );
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            throw new DeviceSummaryObtainingException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            return deviceSummaryMapper.toDto(response.getBody());
        } else {
            throw new DeviceSummaryObtainingException();
        }
    }
```

It is my response Entity:

```
@Data
@Validated
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DeviceSummaryResponse {

    @NotNull
    private ConfigResponse config;

    @NotNull
    private InputStream route;
}
```

but its dont work, HttpMessageConverter error.

How correctly get MultiValueMap<String, Object> by RestTemplate?
Can you give me correct example please?